# How do BLAS libraries implement support for transposed matrices?

Tags: matrix, performance, blas

I'm trying to understand how BLAS libraries implement fast GEMM with support for transposed matrices. Say, I'm only operating on square matrixes (with dimensions `n` by `n`) and I update a submatrix of `c` in the following manner `c[x:x+6][y:y+16] += a[x:x+6][slice_start:slice_end] * b[slice_start:slice_end][y:y+16]` with the following kernel

```c
void kernel(float * a, float * b, float * c, int x, int y, 
            int slice_start, int slice_end, int n,
            bool trans_a, bool trans_b) {

    float result[6][16] = {0};

    for (int k = slice_start; k < slice_end; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            float aa = a[(x + i) * n + k];
            for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                result[i][j] += aa * b[k * n + y + j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            c[(x + i) * n + y + j] += result[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I add support for transposed matrices? If `a` is transposed, I can simply switch the indexes for `aa` retrieval from `a[(x + i) * n + k]` to `a[k * n + (x + i)]`, which wouldn't result in worse performance, since elements of `a` are accessed much less frequently. However, for the same reason, a similar approach wouldn't work for `b`. Not to mention that this approach for `a` accesses elements outside of the kernel window, hindering parallelisation across many threads.

So I was wondering if someone could suggest an approach here? Is there a simple trick? Or is a separate kernel needed for each combination of transpositions necessary? Or is support for transposed matrixes handled outside of the micro-kernel somehow? Or something else entirely?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Blas kernels typically don't deal with transposed matrices. Instead, they will repack matrices (transposed or not) outside of the kernel. See https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/blis3_ipdps14.pdf for details of what the loop nest generally looks like.

Specifically, from the paper (highlighted for emphasis):

> Our description starts with the outer-most loop, indexed by
> jc. This loop partitions C and B into (wide) column panels.
> Next, A and the current column panel of B are partitioned into
> column panels and row panels, respectively, so that the current
> column panel of C (of width nc) is updated as a sequence of
> rank-k updates (with k = kc), indexed by pc. **At this point, the
> GotoBLAS approach packs the current row panel of B into a
> contiguous buffer**, ˜B. If there is an L3 cache, the computation
> is arranged to try to keep ˜B in the L3 cache. The primary
> reason for the outer-most loop, indexed by jc, is to limit the
> amount of workspace required for ˜B, with a secondary reason
> to allow ˜B to remain in the L3 cache.
> **Now, the current panel of A is partitioned into blocks,
> indexed by ic, that are packed into a contiguous buffer**, ˜A.
> The block is sized to occupy a substantial part of the L2
> cache, leaving enough space to ensure that other data does not
> evict the block. **The GotoBLAS approach then implements the
> “block-panel” multiplication of ˜A ˜B as its inner kernel, making
> this the basic unit of computation**

It's not explicitly spelled out, but the pace where you pack panels and blocks is generally where the parts are transposed if necessary.

Comment: i've actually read parts of this paper independently of this, but never crossed that part i guess... could you point me to a specific page in this document where this is described?

Comment: updated with selected quotes

Comment: so essentially (assuming we're in row major order), if a matrix isn't transposed, you partition it into horizontal panels (which means your micro-kernel has linear memory access), and if a matrix is transposed, we partition it into vertical panels? but even so the data isn't contiguous for transposed matrices? or are individual elements supposed to be moved around (not just blocks or panels) in order to ensure contiguous memory access?

Comment: the latter. the packing crates panels such that the microkernel will have contiguous memory by moving things around as needed.

Comment: how come there's virtually no difference in performance when performing GEMM on non-transposed vs transposed matrices? i just did 20000 iterations on two 1024x1024 matrices, and transposed operations actually came out slightly faster

shouldn't the inverse be true given that you have to move individual floats around (which is pretty slow), not to mention that requiring additional temporary storage for transposing panels violates the BLAS spec of additional storage?

Comment: The time is basically the same because the amount of time spent packing the data in either case is very small compared to the O(n^3) computation for the GEMM. Also, iirc, the fastest order (that doesn't transpose either matrix when packing) is if the first matrix is row major and the second is column major (so both of your tests were transposing 1 of the matrices.

Comment: iiuc BLAS GEMM functions don't typically mix data layouts, which is why they only accept a single parameter (row or column major layout) for data layout

could you clarify what you meant by that?

Comment: I mean that in a row major language, B is transposed and A isn't (or vice versa in column major)

Comment: I use the phrasing I did because in a row major language, the transpose of a normal matrix is a normal matrix in a column major language

Comment: aah, i see

one last thing, the parameters trans_a and trans_b (as specified in most GEMM implementations), do they signify whether the matrix has been transposed already (outside of GEMM) or whether the GEMM function itself should transpose the matrices before the performing the multiplication?

Comment: mostly the second (although as mentioned it doesn't transpose the whole thing and instead transposes pieces while repacking)